# Get rows with a duplicate value

Tags: oracle, duplicates

i have the following table structure:

```
+----------+---------+
|       Trade        |
+----------+---------+
| Trade_Id | Book_Id |
+----------+---------+

+---------+-----------+
|      Book           |
+---------+-----------+
| Book_Id | Book_Name |
+---------+-----------+

+----------+--------------+---------------+
|                 Keyword                 |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| Trade_Id | Keyword_Name | Keyword_Value |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to retrieve Trades from a specific book that have one specific duplicate Keyword. I have a query working, but I hate it because I am basically repeating the wohle query in the where-clause.

```
select 
    t.TRADE_ID, 
    kw.KEYWORD_VALUE 
from 
    trade t
    inner join book b               on  b.BOOK_ID = t.BOOK_ID
                                        and b.BOOK_NAME = 'test123'
    inner join TRADE_KEYWORD kw     on  kw.TRADE_ID = t.TRADE_ID
                                        and kw.KEYWORD_NAME = 'ISIN'
where 
    kw.KEYWORD_VALUE in (
        select 
            kw2.KEYWORD_VALUE 
        from 
            trade t2
            inner join book b2              on  b2.BOOK_ID = t2.BOOK_ID
                                                and b2.BOOK_NAME = 'test123'
            inner join TRADE_KEYWORD kw2    on  kw2.TRADE_ID = t2.TRADE_ID
                                                and kw2.KEYWORD_NAME = 'ISIN'
        group by kw2.KEYWORD_VALUE
        having count (*) > 1)
```

How can I do it more elegantly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select TRADE_ID, KEYWORD_VALUE from
    (select 
        t.TRADE_ID, 
        kw.KEYWORD_VALUE,
        count(kw.KEYWORD_VALUE) over(partition by kw.KEYWORD_VALUE) n
    from 
        trade t
        inner join book b               on  b.BOOK_ID = t.BOOK_ID
                                            and b.BOOK_NAME = 'test123'
        inner join TRADE_KEYWORD kw     on  kw.TRADE_ID = t.TRADE_ID
                                            and kw.KEYWORD_NAME = 'ISIN'
    )                               
where n > 1;
```

You may use analitic functions. They are similar to aggregate functions but give a result for each row (PARTITION BY is similar to GROUP BY).

Comment: Nice! Thanks, didnt know analyitc functions before. Will accept your answer in 4 minutes (is still locked)